# vba project reference and shared state (for logging)

Tags: vba, excel

say I have 2 add-ins **A** and **B** - both use VB functions from a shared add-in **C** (i.e. **A** and **B** have a reference to the VB Project **C**).

**C** will log some messages to a file (e.g. `C.Log`) when errors are detected. I want that **C** logs to `A.log` when the functions are called from A and to `B.log` when the functions are called from **B**.

the naive approach to set a global variable in **C** with the log-file name will not work, because the variable is a Singleton, so the last project to set the variable (**A**, or **B**) will win.

How can this easily be done in VBA?

Comment: Create an ILog interface with the file name or log method, have an implementation in a class in A/B and pass that to C.Log(ILog, "" ...)

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4918805/445425) may be of some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay - so here's the solution I came up with (quite some code, but seems to work fine):

I have a **logging project** with a logging interface `ILog` (Instancing `PublicNotCreatable`) like
   this:

```
Public Sub Error(sLogMessage As String)
end sub
Public Sub Warning(sLogMessage As String)
end sub
' etc.
```

and of course an implementing class `CLog` that just writes the messages to a log-file.
and a public function so that the callers can get a new instance of the logger:

```
Public Function New_Log(ByVal logFilePathAndName) As ILog
    Set New_CLog = New CLog
    New_CLog.Initialise logFilePathAndName
End Function
```

then the **project C** must have all it's code in a class/or classes that get an `ILog` instance in their initialisation. For example `CSharedClass` could look like so:

```
Private Log as ILog ' note: the var is intentionally NOT called moLog

Public Sub Initialise(oLogger as ILog)
    Set Log = oLogger
End Sub

' other functions in this class that want to log just use this:
Public Sub SomeProcedure()
    Log.Error("error text")
End Sub
```

also this project must have one public function to let the callers create an instance, like this:

```
Public Sub New_SharedClass(oLogger as ILog) as CSharedClass ' NOTE: you may want to use an interface instead
    Set New_SharedClass = New CSharedClass
    New_SharedClass.Initialise oLogger
End Sub
```

Then **projects A and B** could use the logging like this:

```
Private moLog as ILog

Public Function Log() as ILog
    ' log-file name is of course different for Proejct B
    If moLog is Nothing then Set moLog = New_Log("ProjectA.log")
    Set Log = moLog
End Function
```

all other procedures in project A/B can now write log-messages like this (same as in the shared project)

```
Log.Error("Error text")
```

when project A/B wants to use the shared project, it can do it like so

```
Private moSharedClass as CSharedClass 

Public Function SharedClass() as CSharedClass    
    If moSharedClass is Nothing then Set moSharedClass = New_SharedClass(Log)
    Set SharedClass = moSharedClass
End Function
```

Now any code in project A/B that wants to call a proc on the shared class can simply do this:

```
SharedClass.SomeProcedure()
```

and the log messages written in `SomeProcedure` will end up in the correct log-file

Note: I decided to break some of my own naming rules, so that all projects can use the same code for logging (which has the benefit that I can just move procedures from projects A/B to the shared project or vice versa)